# How to save working notes?

Tags: phpstorm

> How can I save my working notes in phpstorm without creating a new file?

I googled so much but couldn't find for this. Please help me. I would like to add some notes about my websites while working.

Answer (score 8):

There are few ways, that can suit you:

1. **Scratch plugin** (third-party, but stable) http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=4428 .
2. **TODO** functionality: comments in code, that you can see in special view in IDE: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/05/working-with-todo-in-phpstorm/ .

UPD: (Tnx to LazyOne) It's already available under Tools | Create scratch file in 8.0 EAP.
http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program

Comment: FYI: From v8 Scratch plugin will be integrated into IDE

Comment: Can not see it in 8.0 EAP, maybe missing something.

Comment: `Tools | Create Scratch File...`? Official message: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-73814#comment=27-686800

Comment: Only for IDEA EAP (134.1404). Next EAP time for PhpStorm, I suppose.

Comment: The very first v8 EAP (build 134.1456) of PhpStorm is already available for a few days now. And the command is there.

Comment: I was blind but now I see.(c) Thanks a lot for these valuable comments.